# Input segmentation method

Tags: java, android

I am currently trying to find a way to have an input such as "stuff,things,this,that" and then be able to take each separate part and split them into different values so i can use them for different things.

Such as placing them into their own *TextView* locations or to set a timer depending on an input but still be able to use the other information fully.

I have seen this done before using eclipse and i am currently trying to get the code from them but i have gotten no response so far.

Thanks for any help in advance, I have a feeling this is going to be a tough one to do.

EDIT:
I want to use it to edit the values of the results

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LocationFixed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/location"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LocationResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/locationResult" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TimeFixed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/time"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TimeResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/timeResult" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CostFixed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/cost"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CostResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/costResult" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `split` method of the `String` class to separate your string using the delimiter which is a comma.

**example:**

```
 String s = "stuff,things,this,that";
String [] s2 = s.split(",");
System.out.println("1 list" + s2[0]); //result stuff
System.out.println("2 list" + s2[1]); //result things
System.out.println("3 list" + s2[2]); //result this
System.out.println("4 list" + s2[3]); //result that
```

getting the view reference

in `onCreate()`

```
TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LocationFixed); //will get the textview from the layout
t.setText("set The text"); //set the textview text
```

Comment: What would i have to do to call each different ones to apply them to different laid out TextViews. (Give me a min to upload code of what i mean if that would help)

Comment: @Tehjohn editted. do it the same with other textviews

Comment: So to make `LocationResult` "this" I would use `t.setText(s2[2]);`?

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Didn't think ADT has an actual command for this so i thought it would be allot harder.